# How to generate Download file popup in Spring MVC for Angular frontend?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-mvc, download

In my project, I'm want to download docs file which is generating by the system. So in my Springboot backend, I have written controller class to send the request to the frontend,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadDocument/{docId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadDocument(@PathVariable("docId") Integer docId, HttpServletResponse response) {


        log.debug("downloadDocument docId"  + docId);
         try {
             ProjectDocument projectDocument = docRepo.findById(docId);
             InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(projectDocument.getDocument());
             response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + projectDocument.getFileName());
             IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

                response.flushBuffer();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
             log.error(ex);
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        }

    }
```

In my front end, I have no idea to send `HttpServletResponce` into the backend. So what I want to know is,

**01.** Is it mandatory to send `HttpServletResponce` from the frontend?. If it does what should I send as `HttpServletResponce`?

**02.** What is the use of `HttpServletResponce` here?

Comment: what is the response you are getting after adding `{ responseType: 'blob' }`..

Comment: error :Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

Also add `{ responseType: 'blob' }` as options in http get request

```
getGenaratedLetterTemplate(userId): Observable<any> {
  console.log(userId);
  return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl + 'getGeneratedLetter/' + userId,  { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

Component:

`import saveAs from 'file-saver';`

```
  getGenaratedLetterTemplate(userId).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    saveAs(resp, `data.docx`)
  });
```

Comment: Have you installed file-saver?

Comment: error:Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

Comment: This error occurs if you are not passing byte array from backend as response

Comment: try: {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}

Comment: error: (property) observe?: "body"
Type '"response"' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

Comment: Are you using httpclient

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz? Most probably the problem is with the response from backend

Comment: This is the microservices project there are hundreds of components and controllers how can I share slackblitz then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199007/discussion-between-indrajith-ekanayake-and-adrita-sharma).